# Shadowing Inherited State Variables

Tags: solidity, inheritance, state-variable

I was editing and trying out the code from https://solidity-by-example.org/shadowing-inherited-state-variables and got the following output.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract Parent {
    string public name = "Contract Parent";
}

contract Child is Parent {
    constructor() {
        name = "Contract Child";
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }
    string public childGetName = getName();
}
```

```
OUTPUT

childGetName 
"Contract Parent"

getName
"Contract Child"

name
"Contract Child"
```

I want to know why childGetName is not "Contract Child" since the inherited state variable (name) has been overridden.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is because the storage variable `childGetName` gets its value assigned before the constructor code in `Child` is executed (before `name`'s value changes from `"Contract Parent"` to `"Contract Child"`). You could read more about the contract lifecycle [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.3/contracts.html#constructors)

> Before the constructor code is executed, state variables are initialised to their specified value if you initialise them inline, or zero if you do not.